# Trigger jQuery's resizable by an onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I rewrite **ACTION A** to be able to work based on a value passed from a HTML onClick event.

**ACTION A**

```
$("#bt").click(function() {
    var diagonalScl;
    var txSiz;
$("#aTextDV1").resizable({
        alsoResize: '#aText',
        create: function(ui) {
            diagonalScl = diagonalSwItms();
            txSiz = parseInt($("#aText").css("font-size"));
        },
        resize: function(ui) {
            var diagonalSclNw = diagonalSwItms();
            var ratio = diagonalSclNw / diagonalScl;            
            $("#aText").css("font-size", txSiz + ratio * 10);
        }
    });
});
```

Example (Assuming the onClick triggered `myfunc(passedVal)`)

```
function myfunc(passedVal){
    var diagonalScl;
    var txSiz;
    $("#"+passedVal).resizable({
    //so on...
```

Comment: I don't really get what you want.. @.@